# Custom Meteor method call whether the client is logged in

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to customize Meteor methods where before running the desired method, will check if the user is logged in before proceeding to the method?

Ex:

```
Meteor.call('foo',bar,function(){}); //client.js

Meteor.methods({
//check the user if logged in here before proceeding to foo or bazz function
  'foo':function(bar)
        //logic here
  'bazz':function(fizz)
        //logic here
});
```

I can do 
   `this.userId` inside foo function to check but my point is to apply the check if logged in to all the methods before executing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question. With the current API, I don't think you can do this out of the box. However, you can wrap all of your functions before passing them to `Meteor.methods`. If we define a `requireLogin` function like this:

```js
var requireLogin = function(methods) {
  _.each(methods, function(value, key) {
    methods[key] = _.wrap(value, function() {
      // don't bother calling the function if the user isn't logged in
      if (!this.userId)
        throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'You must be logged in.');

      // the wrapped function is always the first argument
      var wrappedFunc = arguments[0];

      // convert the other arguments into an array
      var args = arguments.length > 1 ? Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];

      // call the wrapped function with args and the correct context
      return wrappedFunc.apply(this, args);
    });
  });

  return methods;
};
```

Then we can use `requireLogin` prior to any calls to `Meteor.methods`. For example:

```js
Meteor.methods(requireLogin({
  foo: function(n) {
    console.log("foo: " + n);
  },
  bar: function(n) {
    console.log("bar: " + n);
  }
}));
```

If you wanted to do this for **all** calls, you can further improve this by wrapping `Meteor.methods` itself to use `requireLogin`.

Comment: I think I'm gonna stick to using this.userId for a while ( I'm in prototyping face so it doesn't matter much ) I just asked this because I'll be using it in the future. Thanks for the answer though :).

Comment: Sounds good. I updated the answer to be a little more reusable.